# Acess router config from remote machine

Tags: networking, router

I can't login to my router (`Thomson twg870`) config site from a remote machine (WAN address), even when the "`Remote Config Management`" option is enabled, and custom (not default) credentials are set.
The response is

> bad user name/passwd.

Logging with these same credentials from a local machine (for example 192.168.0.10) works great.
What can be the reason why valid credentials fail when logging in from a remote address?

Comment: Don't know why you can't login, but wouldn't it be safer to make a remote connection to some of your computers in LAN and then access the router? You probably don't want to have the Remote Config Management enabled in the router.

Comment: How can i access the router config (WWW) site on remote machine when i'm remotely logged in on a local machine?

Comment: @Aulis Ronkainen Can You answer my last question?

Comment: Forward a local port to port 80 on the router via SSH tunnel '-L'.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: Yes, I can. Do like @GuyGastineau suggested. Alternatively you can make use of RDP or VNC to create remote desktop connection and then access the router's configuration page with your browser.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -L 1234:192.168.0.1:80 username@yourhomecomputerip`

Replace `username` and `yourhomecomputerip` with their respective values.  Now you can access the router config by pointing your browser at `http://localhost:1234`.
More information about tunneling can be found [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example).

Additionally, you should set up keys for ssh and disable password based connections in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on your home computer acting as the jump server.
Check [this](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/) out for a good starting point.

Good luck.